# Assign output of 'requests' in python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I was using the `requests` module to get some data in JSON form and I want to assign some of the output results into variables in the app; for example the results were like:

```
{'text': 'example',
 'type': 'text'}
```

I wanted to create variables that automatically store `text` as `example` and `type` as `text`.

I tried to create a function and put the first code in it but it didn't work.
The code for it was:

```
import requests
import json
import pprint

def new_func():

    url = '***'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    pprint.pprint(data)
    print(data)

text = new_func.text()
print(text)
```

However, it gives me an error as `text` is not a member of `new_func`.

`text` was part of the output as I mentioned before.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: After it created a function let's say it's name is test I tried to type [text = test.text()] but it says test doesn't have a member called text so I think I made some mistake

Comment: Edit your original question and show your code / any attempts you've done and what the error is, so that someone can help you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? The example code you shared makes little sense.

Comment: @AMC I'm trying to use the data in the output as variables in the original application as I mentioned in the original question the code was a try to see if it will work or not but obviously it didn't work

Comment: @KaiChisaki Maybe you're looking for the `return` statement?

Comment: @AMC Tried it but still no solution.

Comment: @KaiChisaki What do you mean _tried it but still no solution_ ?

Comment: @KaiChisaki Since we can't use your code as we don't know what data you're importing from JSON, does the `data` variable look like `data = {'text': 'some text here', 'type': 'some text here'}`etc. with the ' ' apostrophes around each part? And I assume that you know what is on each line, right? (text, then type, then ... etc)

Comment: @Mandingo Yes you are right, sorry for not putting the url as it contains some private links I can't share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have what is called a dictionary in python.

A dictionary looks like this: `dictionary = {key: value}`

You can get the value of a key using `dictionary.get(key)`

For example, consider the code below:

```
def getValue(key):

    data = {'text': 'some text here',
     'type': 'some text here 2'}

    return data.get(key)

your_value = getValue('type')
```

This function will return `some text here 2` when we get the `type` from `data`

You don't even necessarily need a function for this. You can just have this:

```
data = {'text': 'some text here',
     'type': 'some text here 2'}

your_value = data.get('type')
```

You should be able to apply this to your case.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the JSON module in Python. Below are some links that should help:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, you can wrap any part into a function.

```
import requests

# get response
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')

# parse response:
response_code = response.status_code
response_json = response.json()

# pack response:
packed_response = {
    'text' : response_json,
    'type' : 'text',
    'code' : response_code,        
}
```

More on the requests library here: https://realpython.com/python-requests/